# How to enable source map support for node.js --prof-process

Tags: node.js, profiling, source-maps

I try to profile my (typescript) app, which runs in node.js using the instructions from [the nodejs.org simple profiling guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/). However, the positions are those in the compiled js source file as run by node.

(How) is it possible to enable source map support for the step, to see the locations in the ts source files?

```
node --prof-process isolate-0xnnnnnnnnnnnn-v8.log > processed.txt
```

As of August 2017 I did not yet find a solution...

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I did not actively search. In case you got further than me, you can suggest an edit with the new information and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

After some initial playing around with --prof I found it easier to use Chrome's DevTools. At least for the JavaScript side. DevTools has the advantage of being interactive, and allows you to drill into the underlying .ts code.

1. Start your app with node's `--inspect` flag:

   `node -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register --inspect ./src/index.ts`

   (Here I'm using [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) + [tsconfig-paths](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths) for the typescript handling)
2. Open `chrome://inspect` in Chrome
3. Under "Remote Target" click "inspect" for your new target

   (This should open up a Chrome inspector window connected to your app)
4. Go to the "Profiler" tab and begin recording a new profile

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I rather give you an up vote but won't accept this answer, as it suggests something which helps in the situation but does not solve the command line profiler question.

Comment: But AFAIK `--inspect` start a debugger session not the profiler